# Advice on how to save a secure document as an NFT on the blockchain on a secure website

Tags: nft

I'm very interested in saving some very important digital documents as an NFT on the Cardano blockchain.  I'm very new to NFT's and have some (probably) basic questions for this forum to help in if what I want to accomplish can be done on Cardano.  Here are my thoughts/requriements:

1. We have important digital documents we sign and send via email to our clients.
2. I would like to mint each of these documents as an NFT so this important digital document if ever changed can be proven that it was changed because the minted NFT of the document would be the source of truth.
3. Where do I save this minted NFT document?  I would prefer to be able to save each document on the blockchain with a secure website access.  What I mean by this is our client would need to login to a secure website and each minted NFT document would be available to the client for download.  Or do I need to mint each document as an NFT and build my own traditional website and have each digital document saved on my own server for availability from my own website?
4. How does the ownership of the NFT work?  At the point the NFT is created who owns that NFT?  Do we own it because we minted it?  What about the rights of the NFT for our client?  We did work for our client and created a digital document of our work and signed our name to that document.  Then we'll mint that document as an NFT.  Do we need to transfer the NFT ownership of that document to our client? Or do we keep the rights to the NFT document and yet allow our client access to the digital document for their use.

Any advice this team can provide me in helping me understand how NFT's can be used in creating secure digital documents and how I can distribute these NFT's to our clients.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide some advice based on my own experience. It depends on if you want the documents to be publicly viewable or not.

If they are publicly viewable, you can create an NFT with ipfs links to a document. In this case, you upload the document to IPFS. If you don't want it to be publicly viewable, you can create a hash of the document and mint the nft with metadata that displays that hash. Only the original document will ever match that hash. In this case, you should secure your own copy of the documents and allow the owners to access it. Owners should also be able to check the hash.

Ownership of an NFT is basically whoever controls the wallet the NFT sits in. The NFT can minted in your own wallet or in another wallet that doesn't belong to you. Once an NFT is transferred to someone they own it.